# JQPlot Bar Chart Overlapping and Bar Chart Labels

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart

I have created a horizontal bar chart. I have generated the data for the bar chart from the database in the code behind.

I have two questions regarding the bar chart:

1. The bar charts are displaying but few of them are overlapping. I have tried setting "barPadding" and "barMargin" but that doesn't work.
2. I want to display label against each bar chart stating what each bar represents. These labels are retrieved from the database in code behind and stored in string array. That is against each bar in the bar chart I want to display label like "Accounts", "Telecommunication" etc. These labels are in the array retrieved from database in code behind.

Any inputs on above queries would be much appreciated.

The following is the JQPlot Script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function RunTest() {
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;       

          <% var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();%>
        var industryName = <%= serializer.Serialize(arrIndustryName) %>
        industryPostings = <%= serializer.Serialize(arrIndustryPostings)%>       


        plot = $.jqplot('dispStats', [industryPostings], {
            captureRightClick: true,
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                showAngel: 135,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal',
                    barMargin: 200,
                    barPadding: 500,
                    barWidth: 10,
                    highlightMouseDown: true
                },
                pointLabels: { show: true, formatString: '%d' }
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'e',
                placement: 'outside'
            },
             axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer                    
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>

//asp.net button control to invoke code behind code and run the bar chart script
<asp:Button ID="btnTrends" runat="server" Text="Get Data" OnClick="GetPostingStatistics"    
style="margin-right:10px"/>

<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" Text="Show Trend" OnClientClick="return RunTest()" />
```

The following is the Code Behind Code

```
 protected void GetPostingStatistics(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFromDate = txtFromDate.Text;
        string strToDate = txtToDate.Text;

        switch (ddlTrend.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "Industries":
                {
                    //Code for Sql Connection

                    sql = "select Value from mpats_FieldValue where FieldID =15";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    postingRecords = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(postingRecords);
                    List<string> industryNames = new List<string>();

                    // Code for retrieving labels against each bar from database
                    foreach (DataRow name in postingRecords.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {                        
                        industryNames.Add(name.Field<string>("Value"));
                    }                    

                    int[] numberOfPostings = new int[industryNames.Count];


                    for (int i = 0; i < industryNames.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sql = "select count(p.PostingId) as PostingsCount from 
                               mpats_AdvertPosting p left join mpats_Advert a on p.AdvertID = 
                               a.AdvertID " +
                                "where p.PostingStatusID between 400 and 451 " +
                                "and a.Industry = @Industry";
                                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Industry", industryNames[i]);
                                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                                postingRecords = new DataSet();
                                adapter.Fill(postingRecords);
                                numberOfPostings[i] = Convert.ToInt32(postingRecords.Tables
                                [0].Rows[0]  
                                ["PostingsCount"]);                                           
                    }

                    arrIndustryName = industryNames.ToArray();
                    arrIndustryPostings =  
                    numberOfPostings;                                        

                }
                conn.Close();

                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
    }        
}
```

Thanks

Shwetha